# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

The following are the contents of my `DataTable`. I am trying to add `paging` and `searching` functionalities. However, on checking, I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined

My `.cshtml` code is as follows:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-column-id="Id" data-type="int" data-identifier="true" hidden>ID</th>
        <th data-column-id="DeviceName">Name</th>
        <th data-column-id="DeviceType">Device Type</th>
        <th data-column-id="DeviceManufacturer">Manufacturer Name</th>
        <th data-column-id="ModelNumber">Model</th>
        <th data-column-id="DateOfPurchase">Date of Purchase</th>
        <th data-column-id="Commands">Commands</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

My `jQuery` code is as follows:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        LoadPaging();
        $('#data-table-basic').removeClass("dataTable no-footer");
        //$('table.dataTable').addClass("table table-striped table-vmiddle");
    });

    function LoadPaging() {
        if(@count!= 0)
        {
            var table = $('#data-table-basic').DataTable({
                "pagination": true,
                "bSortable": false,
                "ordering": false,
                "searching": true,
                "bLengthChange": true,
                "info": true,
                //"lengthMenu": [6, 40, 60, 80, 100],
                "lengthMenu":[ [10, 20, 40, 60,80,100, -1], [10, 20, 40, 60,80,100, "All"] ],
                "pageLength": 10,
                language: {
                    paginate: {
                        next: '',
                        previous: ''
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Searching and paging functionalities are not being displayed on the output `View`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `Commands` column is not present in my `model`, I cannot mention is here. Upon removing `<th data-column-id="Commands">Commands</th>`, I was able to see the `paging` and `searching` functionality on my `View`.

The following link helped me figure out what was wrong:
[DataTables.net](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32575/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-dt-cellindex-of-undefined)