# Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '_DT_CellIndex')

Tags: html, jquery, datatable, datatables

jquery.dataTables.min.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '_DT_CellIndex')

Getting this error in the console. Getting data in ajax is in Html not in JSON. tried async:false,column(10).visible(false).But not working

sometimes it works fine and sometimes it throws an error CellIndex. In error case getting data in a single page so pagination not work
Here is my jquery

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: base_url + "get-inventory-report",
            data: 'location_id=' + location_id+'&medicine_id='+medicine_id+'&search_text='+search_text+'&supplier='+supplier,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#LoadingImage').show();
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $('#LoadingImage').hide();
                var inventory_report_refresh =  $('#inventory_report_refresh').val();
                if (result.flag) {
                    if (inventory_report_refresh == 1) {
                        $('#inventory_data_table').DataTable().clear().destroy();
                    }
                    $('.inventory-report').html(result.report_html);
                    $('#dsplay_preview').html(result.report_html);
                    $('.preview-btn').removeClass('hidden');
                        
                    $('#inventory_data_table').DataTable( {
                        "language": {
                            "lengthMenu": langauge_var.common_datatable_show + "_MENU_" + langauge_var.common_datatable_records,
                            "zeroRecords": langauge_var.common_datatable_no_record,
                            "info": langauge_var.common_datatable_show1to + "_MAX_" + langauge_var.common_datatable_of + "_MAX_ " + langauge_var.common_datatable_records,
                            "infoEmpty": langauge_var.common_datatable_no_record,
                            "infoFiltered": langauge_var.common_datatable_filtered + " _MAX_ " + langauge_var.common_datatable_total_record,
                            "sSearch": langauge_var.common_datatable_search,
                            "paginate": {
                                "previous": langauge_var.common_datatable_previous,
                                "next": langauge_var.common_datatable_next
                            }
                        },
                        'pageLength': 10,
                        'aoColumnDefs': [{
                        'bSortable': false,
                        'aTargets': [1,2]
                        }],
                        "sDom": '<"top"fp>t<"bottom"li><"clear">'
                    });
                    $('#inventory_report_refresh').val('1');
                    $('#LoadingImage').hide();
                } else {
                    $.toast({
                        heading: langauge_var.common_error_header,
                        text: result.msg,
                        icon: 'error',
                        hideAfter: 5000,
                        position: 'toast-bottom-right'
                    });
                    if (inventory_report_refresh == 1) {
                        $('#inventory_data_table').DataTable().clear().destroy();
                    }
                    $('.inventory-report').html(result.report_html);
                    $('#dsplay_preview').html(result.report_html);
                    $('.preview-btn').removeClass('hidden');
                    $('#inventory_report_refresh').val('');
                    $('#LoadingImage').hide();
                }
            }
        });
```

HTML

```
 <div class="box-body">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="table-responsive" id="inventoryreport">
                        <table class="table table-bordered theme-table medicine_table inventory-report" id="inventory_data_table">
                            <thead><tr><th>&nbsp;</th></tr> </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="record-error-msg"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>{{trans('common.label_common_no_record')}}</div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>                                
            </div>
```

Comment: Did [any of these previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=_DT_CellIndex) help you?  Specifically [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153908/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-dt-cellindex-of-undefined).     Try giving all your `th`s a full caption (not spaces/whitespace/nbsp)

Comment: tried these solution but not worked

Comment: It would be useful to see the structure of data you're receiving from your ajax request. It looks like you're receiving more than 1 column of data (as you set `'aTargets': [1,2]`) but you have only 1 column defined in your HTML